# Can I call PHP webservices from .Net code?

Tags: .net, web-services

I have a webservice SOAP ( in php), and I have a .Net program that will call that webservice and retrieve results.

Is it doable? Any tutorial on this?

Comment: What do you mean by a .Net program?

Comment: The .Net program is a desktop client that must communicate with the server.

Answer (score 2):

Recently read about WSO2 Web Services Framework for PHP  http://wso2.org/projects/wsf/php

> The framework is capable of dealing
>   with binary attachments, WSDL
>   generation, Web services addressing,
>   policies, security and reliable
>   messaging. It is an open source
>   project, with Apache 2.0 license,
>   there are forums, user and developer
>   mailing lists and an issue tracker.
>
> The framework is inter-operable with
>   non-PHP implementations such as .NET
>   and Java, allowing it to be integrated
>   with enterprise applications
>   seamlessly, hence making PHP a viable
>   option to be used in SOA
>   implementations.

Answer (score 0):

In your .NET application (I'm presuming you're using Visual Studio) add a web reference to the WSDL of your SOAP web service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is doable...

Look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026747/exposing-net-webservice-to-other-platform-java/1026805#1026805).

The same formula applies here. Webservices, be definition should be accessible across language and across platform. Try connecting to this webservice in the same way as you connect to a normal .NET Webservice.

The only gotcha might be the SOAP Version on which webservice is built.

Answer (score 0):

**You can** call **PHP** web service from dot net application Just look at this  tutorial

[1]: http://my-source-codes.blogspot.com/2010/04/access-php-web-service-in-vbnet.html It is explain how to access php web service in dot net application.